# How to Start/Stop TFS Build VMs in vNext after each build

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a highly customized TFS 2013 XAML build workflow. It has customized codes that run on the build controller to Start/Stop a build virtual machine. Is it possible to execute customized task outside of the build agent's machine? If so, where and how.

Answer (score 0):

For the vNext build system, you can add a **Batch Script** or **PowerShell** task as the end task to run any command you needed.

Batch Script for example:

1. Create a cmd file with the command to Start/Stop TFS build VMs.
2. Check in the cmd file.
3. Run the cmd file with Batch Script task.

**If you want to Stop/Start the agent service:** (Reference [this article](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/essential-tools-for-windows-services-net-command/))

```
net stop <Service-Name>
net start <Service-Name>
```

**If you want to shutdown/restart the remote machine:** (Reference [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc770416.aspx))

```
Shutdown : shutdown /m \\machinenameOrIP/s /t 0 
Restart : shutdown /m \\machinenameOrIP /r /t 0
```

**For the commands to Start/Stop VM**, please see this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/hyper-v/start-vm

**Note:**

*Whatever commands you run, make sure the service account has the sufficient permission to run them on the VMs.*

**Update:**

We cannot start the VM in build process if the build VM has been shutdown, because the build service is not started, the build agent must be online.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Yes, the net stop and Shutdown commands within a batch script task at the end of the build will work for me. However, we need VM start command to be run as part of the build processes. The VM start command cannot be run within the build VM since it has been shutdown. With our XAML script, we coded this to run the VM Start command on the build controller portion of the workflow. Is there a similar mechanism in vNext in which customized tasks can be run on the TFS server as part of the build process?

Comment: @A.Poon No, you can't start build agent machine as part of the build process in Vnext build, the build agent must be online.

Comment: I created a batch script to run "Net Stop <service-Name>" and run this as the last step of my build. However, the build ended up failing because communication was lost between TFS and the agent service. Has anyone tried this successfully?